What are the differences between these migrations to make database column non-nullable (Ruby on Rails)?
I have been working with rails recently (pretty new to the whole thing) and I had a question about a concept I was learning about. So I learned about validations that occur at the model-level, but I'm now trying to learn more about database validations. I was wondering if you guys could help answer my questions and check my understanding, as the docs/posts I've found on the topic don't really provide a ground-up explanation.
class AddDeadlineOffsetCheckToTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_check_constraint :templates, "deadline_offset >= 0",
      name: "deadline_offset_non_negative"
  end
end

From my understanding, this example adds a check_constraint which I believe is just code that will ensure that a constraint is enforced on a particular column of a table (at the database level). For example, this constraint here (I think) would simply enforce that for any record saved to the templates table, the deadline_offset value is greater than 0.
My first question here for this example is about the :validates optional argument to add_check_constraint. To my understanding, if this argument is true, as soon as the migration is run, every existing record in the table will be checked to make sure it complies with the constraint, whereas if the argument is false when the migration is run the existing records will not be checked. Is this correct? (The official docs says the argument "specifies whether or not the constraint should be validated. Defaults to true", but I wasn't sure I fully understood this wording.
Continuing on, I started to look at some other examples. I was looking at an example of how to enforce that a certain column be null at the database level. Off of a post, I read that this was bad, because in Postgres "setting NOT NULL on an existing column blocks reads and writes while every row is checked"
class SetSomeColumnNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    change_column_null :users, :some_column, false
  end
end

While I understand why (based off the explanation) this would be bad, my second question is, why couldn't they have just run a migration sort of like this to achieve the same goal?
class SetSomeColumnNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    add_check_constraint :users, "some_column IS NOT NULL", name: "users_some_column_null", validate: true
  end
end

My third and final question is about something I read in the same blog post. They said that the right way to do this for Postgres would be to do the following, and I have no idea why. Could someone please explain each line and why we do it this way, instead of just the above?
class ValidateSomeColumnNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    validate_check_constraint :users, name: "users_some_column_null"
    change_column_null :users, :some_column, false
    remove_check_constraint :users, name: "users_some_column_null"
  end
end


Have you tried running the migrations and seeing what happens to your database? Probably would get a lot more out of that than reading another person's explanation.

1, 2, 3 — this will help you to understand

I think you're missreading and slightly blowing the downsides out of proportion. When you add a NOT NULL constraint to a table all existing rows will be checked and the query will not complete if there are any rows that violate the constraint. You want a lock on the table while that happens to avoid data corruption. Unless your database is huge this doesn't take very long either.
